# Explanation for this C# code to login to youtube

Tags: c#, oop, syntax

I got this piece of code from somewhere in stackoverflow. I am unable to understand it. It is used to login to youtube. Iam new to C# and OOPS. So can anyone explain me few thigs:

1) In the 3rd line

```
 HttpWebRequest request = GetNewRequest("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth", cookies);
```

HttpWebRequest is a class and request is a object. But why New keyword is not used after that? and What is this "GetNewRequest" ? Is it a method? most of the time we use constructor of the class there with New keyword. So can I conclude that I can use any method of the class there? There is no need to use the new keyword and the constructor?

2) In the 6th line

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
```

Dictionary is class and parameters is the object. But what is this `<string, string>` there? I never seen parameters can be passed to a class.

3) In the 7th line

```
{
        {"continue","https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252F"},
        {"service","youtube"},{"uilel","3"},{"dsh","157212168103955870"},{"hl","en_US"},
        {"GALX","PTqcwpZb2aE"},{"pstMsg","1"},{"dnConn",""}, {"checkConnection","youtube%3A248%3A1"}, 
        {"checkedDomains","youtube"}, {"timeStmp",""}, {"secTok",""}, {"Email","username"}, {"Passwd","password"}, 
        {"signIn","Sign+in"}, {"PersistentCookie","yes"}, {"rmShown","1"}};
```

I can't understand what is this? It cant fit to any syntax I read in C#. It is something I have never seen before.

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
public void Login()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = GetNewRequest("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth", cookies);
    request.Referer = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252F&uilel=3&hl=en_US&service=youtube";
    request.Host = "accounts.google.com";
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>{
        {"continue","https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252F"},
        {"service","youtube"},{"uilel","3"},{"dsh","157212168103955870"},{"hl","en_US"},
        {"GALX","PTqcwpZb2aE"},{"pstMsg","1"},{"dnConn",""}, {"checkConnection","youtube%3A248%3A1"}, 
        {"checkedDomains","youtube"}, {"timeStmp",""}, {"secTok",""}, {"Email","username"}, {"Passwd","password"}, 
        {"signIn","Sign+in"}, {"PersistentCookie","yes"}, {"rmShown","1"}};
    HttpWebResponse response = MakeRequest(request, cookies, parameters);
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: GetNewRequest is method in your code which creates the new obkect. The dictionary object is being initialized with key value pairs of string, string. You might be better off debugging through your code for point 1. and Look at dictionary constructors on MSDN for points 2 and 3.

Comment: looks like something similar to cookies

Comment: Parameters for a class are template parameters and tell it which data type it uses. So you can write on class MyList that takes a template parameter and you can use it for Int, String, MyOtherSuperClass without writing your list for each of them.

Comment: Actually...`request` is a reference to  a `HttpWebRequest` object.  Its pretty clear based on the context that `GetNewRequest` is a static method that returns a reference to a `HttpWebRequest` object.  A `Dictionary` is a collection the question you asked about that is syntax sugar to add those strings into the collection.  All your questions could have been answered with a little research on your part.

Comment: -1 for this question? Life is not easy for newbies at stackoverflow anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `GetNewRequest` would be a method that actually creates and returns the instance of `HttpWebRequest`. So, `new` is not needed before the call to `GetNewRequest`. `new` is only needed when you are calling the constructor of the type in that same line as the declaration.
2. The `<string, string>` declaration after `Dictionary` specifies the key and value types, since `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a [generic type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
3. That is a way of initializing a dictionary with a list of key/value pairs. It's just syntactic sugar. See [Object Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx). It's just there to make your life easier/code more concise. That code is equivalent to the more verbose:

_

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("continue","https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252F");
parameters.Add("service","youtube");
// etc.
```

Comment: well, the 'new' is used/needed in the GetNewRequest function, guess it's clear to you and me but maybe not to the questioneer. Aside from that your explanation is way better than mine. Haven an upvote

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Thanks. I'll reword it to try and make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. `GetNewRequest` is a method which is not defined in the code you posted.
2. `Dictionary<string, string>` the `<` and `>` signs are used for generics, see
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for an introduction.
3. Is the syntax for initializing the values of the dictionary, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx